# Table Mapping mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a problem and my friend says I must use table mapping... but I don't know what is table mapping and I don't know if, what I'm going to do, is right or not

I have this table: *employee*

```
+-------+------------+------+-------------------------+
| ac_no | department | rank | email                   |
+-------+------------+------+-------------------------+
| 12ac  |  01        | 08   | bla@vla.com             |
| 1an4  |  02        | 08   | jla@jla.com             |
| dr17  |  01        | 08   | dre@dre.com             |
| 13IN  |  01        | 05   | adjre@jre.com           |
| TE12  |  02        | 05   | drew@dre.com            |
| GR45  |  01        | 05   | noide@idea.com          |
+-------+------------+------+-------------------------+
```

From data on table *employee* I must insert into table mapping

The goal is to get all the data that has rank 08

```
+-------+------------+------+-------------------------+
| 12ac  |  01        | 08   | bla@vla.com             |
| 1an4  |  02        | 08   | jla@jla.com             |
| dr17  |  01        | 08   | dre@dre.com             |
+-------+------------+------+-------------------------+
```

And look for the data which has rank 05 and are in the same department, and then get the email...if data more than one the email will split with;

```
+-------+---------------+------------+------------------------------+
| ac_no |email          | department |               email          |
+-------+---------------+------------+------------------------------+
| 12ac  | bla@vla.com   |   01       | adjre@jre.com;noide@idea.com |
| 1an4  | jla@jla.com   |   02       | drew@dre.com                 |
| dr17  | dre@dre.com   |   01       | adjre@jre.com;noide@idea.com |
+-------+---------------+------------+------------------------------+
```

I want to use procedure to process data from table *employee* into table *mapping*, but I don't know how to get that. I make a procedure on workbench and run it, to insert data into table mapping.

```
select ac_no,department,rank,email,(select department,email from employee where rank=05)head from employee where rank=08;
```

But if I run this query the result `subquery returns more than 1 row`

Sorry if I ask the basic question, but I really don't know how to do this.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but I think you want a through table using foreign keys and innoDB.  Should look at a normalized database

Comment: @bigman If it's a small database, ok, but when you have a really large database, denormalizing will greatly increase performance. You can do joins to get the data you need anyway. Just check everything before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
select ac_no,department,rank,email from employee where rank = 08 and where department =  all(select department from employee group by department)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(select ac_no,department,rank,email from employee where rank=8) UNION (select ac_no,department,rank,email from employee where (rank,department) in (select rank,department from employee where rank=5 group by department having count(*)>1))
```

Returns data of all employees :

1) with rank 8 irrespective of department

2) with rank 5 having atleast one more employee with rank 5 belonging to the same department

Comment: @Belajar hmmm... I tried running it myself. And it worked fine. Data with non matching ranks were not returned